# MySQL query from different tables with same city

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables:

```
Processor(_pid_, brand, clockSpeed, supplierCity)

Memory(_mid_, brand, capacity, supplierCity)

Harddrive(_hdid_, brand, capacity, RPM, supplierCity)

PC(_pcid_, _mid_, _pid_, _hdid_, model, price, cost)
```

I am trying to build a query that:

```
Find's the PC model whose price is less than 1000 pounds and for which 
the memory and the processor are supplied from the same city
```

My Current query returns multiple repetition of same result:

```
SELECT pc.model FROM pc, memory, processor WHERE
memory.supplierCity=processor.supplierCity AND pc.price<1000;
```

[image]

Comment: abandon old style joins. In your query there is a cross product being performed, because table `pc` isn't joined. First `join` the tables and then you will see the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    pc
WHERE   price < 1000
        AND EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    processor p
        JOIN    memory m
        USING   (supplierCity)
        WHERE   (p._pid_, m._mid_) = (pc._pid_, pc._mid_)
        )
```

Comment: I would not recommend this. Subqueries in WHERE clauses (at least in MySQL) are generally VERY inefficient. Combine that with joining every memory in a city to every processor in a city an then only checking afterward to find if there is a pairing that exists that matches the pc components, and then doing that again and again for each pc whose price is below 1000, and you've got a recipe for a resource hog.

Comment: @Uueerdo: MySQL's optimizer is not the sharpest pencil in the box of course, but the join order is something it can handle. In particular, it will not join every processor to every memory: it will first look them up by id from pc, then check if their cities match.

Comment: Best case scenario, the optimizer will do that, though I hate relying on the optimizer when I've had use `SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN` on numerous occasions; however, it is my understanding that even best case scenario for the optimizer, it will still run that subquery separately for every pc record whose price is below 1000 since that is a correlated subquery.

Comment: @Uueerdo: yes it's exactly what it will do, and in your own post you're mentioning this as a good thing.

Comment: Running the subquery separately for each row is NOT a good thing, especially if it resulting in ignoring indexes that could greatly improve performance. I'm not sure what I stated that would suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Uueerdo: with all due respect, do you know how MySQL optimizer works? Why on earth would it ignore indexes? How is doing two PK lookups in a subquery different from doing the same thing in a join?

Comment: For one, separate indexes on `_pid_` and `_mid_` are not equivalent to a compound index on the JOIN results of those two tables; it is giving the optimizer the benefit of the doubt that it would not ignore them completely with at where clause on lists like that. For another, in JOINs MySQL often joins the indexes, rather than entire the rows themselves. With a JOIN, the join is performed once with the tables involved; with correlated subqueries, the subquery is often executed once for each row in the the outer query it is correlated with.

Answer (score 0):

As vkp said in comments, try to stay away from the comma notation as much as possible (*the cases where it is helpful and not just lazy are usually simple and rare*). Also, like vkp said, `pc` wasn't joined, as shown below.

```
SELECT pc.model 
FROM pc
   INNER JOIN memory ON pc.`_mid_` = memory.`_mid_`
   INNER JOIN processor ON pc.`_pid_` = processor.`_pid_` 
WHERE pc.price<1000 
   AND memory.supplierCity=processor.supplierCity
;
```

The `AND` portion can be moved to the second `ON` clause, and might be more efficient depending on your data; but conceptually this is easier to explain.

It gets a list of all pc records with their corresponding memory and processor, and then keeps results where the pc is priced less than 1000 and the memory and processor are supplied by the same city. However, due to how MySQL usually processes queries, it is very likely it will get the list of sub-1000 priced pc entries first and then find the memory and processor for each of those.